# Jquery select is selected than add class

Tags: jquery

I am learning Jquery. I am trying to to understand the selected options.
So when user select a option I can do something.

I trying to run Jquery so that when the user selects customAmountSelected that it should add a class 'xxx' to customAmountinput

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#amountSelected:selected").val() == 'customAmountSelected') {
    $('.customAmountinput').addClass('xxx');
  }
});
```

```css
.displaynone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Budget (&pound;)</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="amountSelected">
      <option selected="selected">No budget</option>
      <option value="5">£5</option>
      <option value="30">£10</option>
      <option value="20">£20</option>
      <option value="50">£50</option>
      <option value="100">£100</option>
      <option value="customAmountSelected">Custom</option>
    </select>
    <p class="small"><em>Need some text here to explain why they can edit budget </em>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- appear when user selected custom budget -->
  <div class="form-group displaynone customAmountinput">
    <label>Enter ammount</label>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="&pound;">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value checked>Post to wall?
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling value, so you don't need to validate the "selected" state.

You must listen to the event "change", and it must be inside the $(document).ready(), that kind of events are binded in the window/DOM load.

Try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#amountSelected").change(function(){ 
     if($(this).val() == 'customAmountSelected'){
       $('.customAmountinput').addClass('xxx');
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is incomplete as it does not remove the class when other options are selected.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the if statement on the wrong place. This way the `if` is evaluated once on document load and that's it. You'll need to bind that to the `change` event of the input like so:

```
$("amountSelected").change(function(){
        if($("#amountSelected:selected").val() == 'customAmountSelected' ) {
            $('.customAmountinput').addClass('xxx');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Velimir for the prompt reply. Could explain in more simple words what you mean by "This way the if is evaluated once on document load and that's it. ". What do you mean by the words "evaluated"

Comment: the function runs/is executed only once - exactly when the page loads. Even simpler you are saying "run this code once, when the page loads" and you want to say "run this code every time I change the value of the `select`"

Answer (score 0):

While changing the option, the jQuery `.change` event gets triggered. Note that, for getting the value, just use `this.value`

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ke41atfp/3/)

```
$("#amountSelected").change(function() {
  if (this.value == 'customAmountSelected') {
    $(".customAmountinput").toggleClass("displaynone xxx");
  } else {
    $(".customAmountinput").addClass("displaynone");
    $('.customAmountinput').removeClass('xxx');
  }
});
```

Comment: Note: toggleClass can toggle multiple classes *at the same time*. No need to duplicate code (not to mention you have the same code in both sides of the `if`, making that pointless) :)